# How to "hide" (return status = 0) from isql stored procedure result?

Tags: sql, sap-ase, isql

When I execute stored procedures using isql, they might give this info:

```
(return status = 0)
```

Is it possible to disable that info?

I already use `SET NOCOUNT ON` to disable some part but this is still presented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
set proc_return_status off
```

Be aware that you disable for all SPs in the current database, you should:

```
set proc_return_status on
```

afterwards.